# route some traffic in subnet to other gateway

Tags: iptables, route

I want to route traffic destined for 192.168.5.0/24 to a gateway of 10.1.10.24, but all other traffic to a gateway of 10.1.10.1. I tried:

```
ip route add 192.168.5.0/24 via 10.1.10.24
```

but it seems to be getting a response from an upstream router on from 10.1.10.1, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the route only affects outgoing outgoing traffic, not return traffic.  So possibly your route is being respected, but the particular router you are talking to is replying from a different address.

If that is not the case, then to debug the problem further I would recommend first running `ip route get 192.168.5.1` or whatever address you are trying to reach, just to make sure your routing table is sane.

Then I would recommend running `traceroute 192.168.5.1` (or `tracepath`, `mtr`, whatever happens to be installed on your machine).  That will show the next hop you are going to.